# TBlobField(<Field>).SaveToStream cut the last NULL char with delphi 2010

Tags: blob, delphi-2010

If a blob contain a rtf that end with NULL char, delphi 2010 cut this character when I do SaveToStream or SaveToFile

Is There a possibility to change this behavior?

It is a problem for me because I calculate a hash on that fields. 
With Delphi 2010 I have this problem but not with Delphi 2007! and so hash result change....

Comment: Why does the RTF end with a NULL character to being with? It shouldn't. RTF is a plain ASCII-based text format, NULL does not belong in it.

Comment: I don't know why. But in my database is so :(

Comment: I also try to set BlobType at ftTypedBinary but nothing, sometimes it save correctly and sometimes not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found when the bug appear:

1. Delphi 2010
2. Firebird DBMS
3. TIBDatabase object have the charset property (in
   my case for example  *lc_ctype=ISO8859_1*)

If I **remove the charset**, the save method work fine!

Other information:
- I use Firebird database
- The blob field is blob subtype text
- The value is a rtf and his terminator is null character

**NOTE:** 
When remove the charset, the text in blob fields are not readable correctly, the only workaround I have found is cast the blob in varchar directly in the query